# App store testing an Application with inapp purchase feature

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have a few questions regarding inApp Purchase as follows:

1. Do we need to make a product (in App purchase) live before submission or we can make it after app approval. 
   Suppose I have a product in inApp Purchase that is to be in sale by Next week, and if my app with inApp purchase version gets approved this week, then how do the Apple store test my app.
2. Do any one know how the ***apple app store guys test the inApp purchase*** in the application. Do they buy our product in the inApp purchases and then test the product. What does the screen shot submitted to approve the product in iTunes for inApp Purchase refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Apple submission is largely guesswork.

I don't think you need to worry about how Apple test the In-App Purchase. If your app currently has no purchases available for it; but it still works, then I would think that's okay.

From a 'making-your-users-happy' point of view it would make sense to be able to buy at least some In-App content the day it goes live - but I don't think it would be necessary to pass Apple approval.

The screen shot is supposed to show what the user gets in return for their purchase. However, that can be tough - just do the best you can. We have an In-App purchase for the 'full version' of a game, to demonstrate that I just used the splash screen of the game. It passed.